# Helm won't let me select available emacs commands

Tags: helm

I have emacs set up so that when I type `M-x` the helm completion buffer pops up. My problem is that helm wont let me select `M-x align` if I have previously called `M-x align-current`, because it is only letting me select the completion from the Command History List and not the list of all available commands.

Any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you have `M-x` mapped to `helm-M-x`?

Comment: Yes, I do have `M-x` mapped to `helm-M-x`.

Comment: have you tried `(helm-autoresize-mode t)` ? This should resize the helm buffer to fit the completions, it may then also show the list of all available commands (not only the command history).

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can press `C-o` to switch to the other list (I also found this behaviour unintuitive when I started using Helm).
Alternatively, if you want to always be able to move to the Emacs Command list, evaluate the following snippet:

```
(setq helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source nil)
```

Here's a duplicate as a Github issue:
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/683

And here's a duplicate from SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645582/emacs-helm-m-x-how-to-jump-to-the-list-of-historical-command

To read the helm M-x documentation you can press `C-c ?` after invoking helm.

Comment: Thank you very much. `C-o` was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.